Concurrency - Inserting to a map only if record has a certain status
I have the below code snippet that I want to change. Currently, it reads from a list and creates a map keyed on transactionId and it overrides the element stored in the map irrespective of the status of the object. PaymentDetailsModel contains as attributes the transaction id and the status.
        Map<String, PaymentDetailsModel> transactions = new HashMap<>();
        allPaymentActivityRecords.stream()
                .forEach(paymentDetail -> transactions.put(paymentDetail.getTransactionId(), paymentDetail));
        return transactions;

I want to change it so that the override doesn't occur if the stored value has STATUS2 and the coming record has STATUS1.
In the code, it would look something like this:
private Map<String, PaymentDetailsModel> process(List<PaymentDetailsModel> allPaymentActivityRecords){
        Map<String, PaymentDetailsModel> transactions = new HashMap<>();

        for (PaymentDetailsModel paymentDetail : allPaymentActivityRecords) {
            PaymentDetailsModel paymentDetailsModel = transactions(paymentDetail.getTransactionId());
            if (paymentDetailsModel == null || !shouldNotOverrideStates(paymentDetail, paymentDetailsModel)) {
                transactions.put(paymentDetail.getTransactionId(), paymentDetail);
            }
        }
        return transactions;

   private static boolean shouldNotOverrideStates(PaymentDetailsModel paymentDetail, PaymentDetailsModel paymentDetailsModel) {
        return STATUS2.equals(paymentDetailsModel.getStatus()) && STATUS1.equals(paymentDetail.getStatus());
    }

My concern is that this solution could suffer from concurrency issues if this code is run in parallel on multiple threads. Among the ideas to ensure correctness, I have the synchronisation on the condition or using ConcurrentHashMap. Please let me know your thoughts.

This question is similar to: Java concurrency with a Map of Lists. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is not the same question, it is not about changing a list, but about processing the elements from the list and set the corresponding map element only if the status of the upcoming element has certain values.

You should use ConcurrentHashMap and its merge method, which is processed atomically:
    Map<String, PaymentDetailsModel> transactions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    for (PaymentDetailsModel paymentDetail : allPaymentActivityRecords) {
        transactions.merge(
                paymentDetail.getTransactionId(),
                paymentDetail,
                (existingValue, newValue) -> {
                    if (shouldNotOverrideStates(newValue, existingValue)) {
                        return existingValue;
                    } else {
                        return newValue;
                    }
                }
        );
    }


I tried this and it didn't override the event correctly. It seems to pass if I use compute: transactions.compute(
upcomingPaymentDetail.getTransactionId(),
(k, v) -> {
if (v == null || ! shouldNotOverrideStates(upcomingPaymentDetail, v)) {
return upcomingPaymentDetail;
} else {
return v;
}
}
);

I debugged what happens with merge and if it receives a list with events with STATUS2, then STATUS1, it doesn't put in the map STATUS2, it only puts STATUS1, which is incorrect.

Initially the map will return null for the transactionId, and it looks like merge is not replacing it.

@user998692 I think I had the arguments to shouldNotOverrideStates the wrong way around. Edited just now. Please retry the fix.

Also, edited again to use meaningful value names and corrected the if statement.

I tried your fix and retested, but it's still not working.

regarding to "Initially the map will return null for the transactionId": the JavaDoc of ConcurrentHashMap clearly states that "Like Hashtable but unlike HashMap, this class does not allow null to be used as a key or value." - so for null keys you cannot use it.

Null is the value, what I meant to say was that initially when it checks for that trasactionId, it returns null, then it should save the first event, then only save the second event to override the first if the states are not STATUS2 for existing event and STATUS1 for the upcoming one.

And note that reads are not synchronized with writes - so while writing will always produce a valid state of the Map, reading will not necessarily return the values you expect. Maybe you should switch over to a Hashtable, but this will have (negative) impact on the performance.

On the second (third) thought: you are modifying your map based on the contents that it already has. If you do this in parallel, you have to take special care that entries of one key value are always processed in "incoming order", so you should process your activity records by transaction ID per thread, so that one transaction ID is always processed by the same thread, so the order of the incoming activities is maintained.

@cyberbrain To give you more context, this is from a component which receives messages over a Kafka topic from a payments system. The payment takes place in 2 phases, and it is possible that the message for phase 1 arrives after the message for phase 2. In the original implementation, you can see that this message would override the one for phase 2, which is not what is required. What's needed is to keep the phase 2 message if it's already in the map, otherwise store the message for phase 1. I hope this brings more clarity to the ask.

I had got mixed up between merge and compute and had got it wrong initially. Now corrected.

I have tested my finally corrected version and this self-contained executable snippet proves that it works correctly: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/1eEt . Apologies for misleading with buggy versions earlier.
